# FFI Stubs in GHC 7

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

I'm trying to compile a Haskell module with some FFI code in it. It used to work under the old Haskell Platform with GHC 6 and a custom GHC 7 to get the 64 bit version.

Upgrading to the latest Haskell Platform with 64 bit version of GHC 7 has stopped it from working. It seems like GCC is having some trouble with the stub files that GHC spits out - they use GHC Framework headers that are having trouble finding standard C files. Here's just one of the many errors I'm getting:

```
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.0.2-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include/Stg.h:62:18:
    error: math.h: No such file or directory
```

I seem to have the same problem with the 32 bit version of the Platform, and the same standard files work correctly in normal GCC compilations. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the latest version of XCode and ghc 7.0.2.  Ghc 7.0.3 supposedly fixes this.